# IBM Watson cloud ALPN name?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

I've come to know that for amazon aws connection using psoc6 (cypress board) and modus toolbox sample code i.e. anycloud mqtt client , the ALPN(application layer protocol negotiation) is "x-amzn-mqtt-ca" which is on port 443 likewise is what is the ALPN for IBM Watson?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ALPN isn't supported on IBM Watson IoT Platform. If you want to connect via port 443 then you can use HTTPS as described on this page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP8H/iot/platform/reference/mqtt/index.html